# Connection of MySQL with PHP not working

Tags: php, mysql, linux, apache, mysqli

This is my situation:

I'm trying to connect to my MySQL database with a PHP file on my Apache server, now: my PHP can connect to the MySQL database when I run it from the terminal (using `"php -f file.php"`) but when I execute it from a web page it just doesn't connect.

This is my php file:

```
echo "TRY CONNECTION";
$conn = mysql_connect($servername, $username, $password);
echo "EXECUTED CONNECTION";
```

The Linux shell prints this:

> TRY CONNECTIONEXECUTED CONNECTION

But the web page prints this:

> :TRY CONNECTION

I tried using mysqli but the result is the same

Comment: How are you setting $servername, $username, and $password? Please provide just sample credentials and not your actual ones!

Comment: Check for mysqli_error() after your connection, and check your error logs on the server. Stay away from the mysql_* functions as they've been removed in PHP7 and deprecated in all previous versions because they are horribly insecure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
 echo "TRY CONNECTION";
 $conn =new mysqli($servername, $username, $password,$database);
 echo "EXECUTED CONNECTION";
```

or may be this

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
```

Comment: It's much better to use the object-oriented interface: [`new mysqli(...)`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php) than the procedural style. Not only is it less verbose, but it avoids mistakes with using `mysql_query` by accident.

Answer (score 0):

Which MySQL version you use?

```html
define('HOST_NAME', 'localhost');
define('DB_NAME', 'test');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASS', '');
// DB Connections
$db = mysql_connect(HOST_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
if($db){
    if(mysql_selectdb(DB_NAME, $db)){
        //echo 'DB Connected.';
    }else{
        echo mysql_errno();
    }
}else{
    echo mysql_error();
}

or used below one
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli(HOST_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";
```